# Ubuntu 15.04 intalled on older computer is running slow

Tags: performance

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 on an older computer because it could not handle many of the features included with Windows Vista. I thought I would try Ubuntu to improve performance. However it isn't running any better. Is there a way to remove some of the less important features of the Ubuntu O.S. to improve the performance of this older computer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default Ubuntu?

Try some derivates like Xubuntu or Lubuntu because they use a window manager that uses less resources than Gnome, which is the default window manager for Ubuntu.

You can also try installing XFCE (the window manager from Xubuntu) or LXDE (the window manager from Lubuntu) manually and use them (but tis is a bit more difficult than simply use a derivate and istall this).

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can improve performance and run Ubuntu on even less powered computers. What will help you to achieve this is to choose a lighter window manager.

And, along with @Uwe Plonus sugestions *(Xubuntu or Lubuntu)*, I have tested and recommend [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)

I know this implies in a new/fresh install, but it's worth every minute spent.

---

Ah! Welcome to Ubuntu family and ask us whenever you need!